# Date validation Oracle SQL 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to find all the vehicles that are used for these dates including the vehicles that may start at a date between departure and return or finish later at the stated return date(which the user declares). Any suggestions?

```
SELECT REGISTRATION,VEHICLE_TYPE_ID
    FROM VEHICLE
    INNER JOIN TRIP
    ON (TRIP.VEHICLE_REGISTRATION=REGISTRATION)
    where (TRIP.DEPARTURE) >= '02-JAN-12' AND (TRIP.RETURN) <= '04-JAN-12'
    GROUP BY VEHICLE.REGISTRATION,VEHICLE.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID;
```

Comment: Does your query as written produce your expected output?

Comment: No , it provides me only the vehicles that are used between those dates.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you're after this:

```
select   v.registration,
         v.vehicle_type_id
from     vehicle v
         inner join trip t on (t.vehicle_registration = v.registration)
where    t.return >= to_date('02/01/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and      t.departure <= to_date('04/01/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by v.registration,
         v.vehicle_type_id;
```

N.B. you'll note that I explictly converted your date-as-strings into DATEs by using to_date. This is good practice and will prevent bugs, which may well happen if your `nls_date_format` parameter is set to something other than the default 'dd-MON-rr'.

Why make Oracle guess (aka implicitly convert) what date you meant when you can specify it exactly?

Comment: This is what i was looking for ! Thanks !!